# Listening query with data filtering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure

```
comments:
 - FG1MaPfTFsdgdsgsruL9Cgx5sY2
   + content
     + value: "My comment"
   + creator: "0U1MaPfTF2fwcgqWuruL9Cgx5sY2"
   + date_create: "2015-02-21T12:40:35Z"
   + users[]
     + CByXgSgB4khZ5LgugXGRdfK7CLk2
     + XakJ8zn711bUeSpCK1ss7Fsz7JX2
   + relations[]
     + HTyXgSgB4khZ5LgugXGRdfK7CLk2
     + CakJ8zn711bUeSpCK1ss7Fsz7JX2
   + settings[]
     + duration: 2
```

How to write the appropriate query listening in the application so that when the `user UID` appears in `users[]` it will immediately receive a message.

An additional filter will be time in `duration`

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I want to filter the collection on an ongoing basis to use the object only if my UID is on the list in this object and meets the date condition

Comment: u are using realtime database not firestore right?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Realtime Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the user uid:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var uid;

if (user != null) {
  uid = user.uid;
  let database     = firebase.database();
  let userRef      = database.ref("users").orderByKey().equalTo(uid);
    userRef.on('value', ((snapshot) => {
    if(snapshot.exists()){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
      } 
   });
}
```

Try the above, first retrieve the `uid` then add a reference to node `users` and using `orderByKey()` you can query on the `uid`, and then using `exists()` you can check if it exists in the database or not.

Comment: Do I think that if I do not call the `on` or `once` function, then the database query will not go and will not download any data?

Comment: `on` and `once` are used to retrieve data so they will download data..in your case also its better to use `once` and not `on` if you want to limit

Comment: `let userRef  = database.ref("users").orderByKey().equalTo(uid);` How is it Does it just set the filter or already sends a query and saves the result in a variable?

Comment: This just sets the filters and when you attach an event to it using `once`, you can then retrieve the result, this `let userRef = database.ref("users").orderByKey().equalTo(uid);` doesnt give u the result. This is the result `snapshot.val()`

Comment: did you understand?

Comment: This is what we have already understood. It's just that I have two filters to do. and Everyone checks if the value is in the collection. The first filter checks if my UID is in the `users[]` collection. The second filter checks if the `relations` UID of the object that I have in my favorite collection. I have a collection of several items and I need to check if one of these items is in the `relations[]` collection. Look at the data in the body of the issue

Comment: Only one condition must be met. Either meets the `user` or meets the condition for `relations`

Comment: I meant myself and your with explanation